# nginx - proxy facebook/bots to a different server without changing canonical URL

Tags: vue.js, nginx, seo, prerender

**TLDR;
How can I make it so that all scraper/bot requests reaching my frontend `https://frontend.example.test/any/path/here` are fed the data from `https://backend.example.test/prerender/any/path/here` without changing the canonical URL?**

I have a complex situation where I have a Vue app that pulls data from a php API to render data. These are hosted in China so niceties like netlify prerender and prerender.io are not an option.

Initially I tried:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp") {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://backend.example.test/prerender/$1 redirect;
}
```

which workd but Facebook used `backend.example.text` the canonical URL `frontend.example.test`.

Setting the `og:url` to the frontend app caused problems due to a redirect loop. I tried then setting the `og:url` to the frontend with a query param that skipped the nginx forward, but for some reason this wasn't working properly on the live server and I imagine facebook would still end up pulling the data from the final url anyhow.

Thus I imagine the only solution is to use `proxy_pass` but it is not permitted with a URI inside an `if` statement (and I have read the [if is evil article](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

I feel like all I need is something like a functioning version of:

```
location / {
  if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp") {
    proxy_pass https://backend.example.test/prerender;
  }
  ...
}

(I am of course aware of the contradiction of having to have Facebook sharing work in China, but the client is requesting this for their international users as well).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem:

https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/934/nginx-proper-way-different-upstream-user-agent-based-reverse-proxying-rule-without-if

I'm copying here the main parts in case the link breaks:

Create a dynamic target upstream with the map directive:

```
map "$http_user_agent" $targetupstream {
  default        http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  "~^mybot"      http://127.0.0.1:8090;
}
```

Here "~^mybot" is a regular expression, if the user agent matches that expression it will use that upstream server.
If the user-agent does not match any entries, Nginx will use the "default" entry (saving http://127.0.0.1:8080 as $targetupstream variable).

Then you just have to use a that upstream in a proxy pass setting:

```
  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass $targetupstream;
  }
```

Now, you could use one upstream pointing to locahost at a port that is being used by nginx to serve static files (for client only) and another port for the server renderer.

Comment: it is not clear to me what domain should someone put on the default one. How to achieve  in the default case nginx would use is try_files to serve the content?

Comment: The user reaches nginx through port 80 or 443(ssl).
In your nginx configuration you could create a http block, that serves requests in port 8080, in that http block you will serve files with try_files. When it is a user, you will set targetupstream to port 8080 which will redirect the request back to nginx at that "try_files" configuration block, when it is a bot it will redirect the request to port 8090 which has the server side rendering server listening in.